Pandas replacing Excel values inconsistently
I'm using the syntax below to replace only specific values in the 'content_text' column based on the macro_id column in my spreadsheet, however the results are very inconsistent.
Essentially the macros are numbers that represent text and they are all uniform as far as character count and delimiters, however, and I cannot figure out why some macro ids never get replaced.
There are instances where there are multiple macro_ids in the context field but sometimes they aren't replaced when there is only one.
There are only about 4200 rows and I'm really hoping my laptop isn't just tapping out.
import pandas as pd
import re

# Read the large spreadsheet with 11 thousand rows
df = pd.read_excel('testmacros.xlsx')


# Handle NaN values in 'content_text' column
df['content_text'] = df['content_text'].fillna('')


# Update values in the 'content_text' column using the map function
s = df.astype({'macro_id': str}).set_index('macro_id')['content_text']

pattern = r'\b(%s)\b' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, s.index))

df['content_text'] = (df['content_text']
                            .str.replace(pattern,
                                         lambda m: s.get(m.group(0)),
                                         regex=True)
                           )

# Save the updated large spreadsheet
df.to_excel('updatedmacros.xlsx', index=False)

Example:
What  I have



macro_id
content_text




5678111123
The Department of Health


5678114567
All personnel reporting late should call the 5678114568


5678114568
Front desk phone line at 1-555-555-5555


5678112222
Patients with a fever 300 should report to 5678114568 and contact  5678111123



What should return



macro_id
content_text




5678111123
The Department of Health


5678114567
All personnel reporting late should call the Front desk phone line at 1-555-555-5555


5678114568
Front desk phone line at 1-555-555-5555


5678112222
Patients with a fever 300 should report to Front desk phone line at 1-555-555-5555 and contact  The Department of Health



I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and sometimes when I run the code I get at least 8 rows that didn't convert, though it's gotten up to 186.
I've spot checked multiple macro_ids and confirmed they are valid and tie to text. 
The values on the original sheet were loading directly from a Power Query and I've played with changing the field type from number to text which is where I see the fluctuations in rows that didn't convert.
I've pasted the values as text into separate sheets for xlsx and csv formatting but I never get 100% replacement.
What could I be doing wrong?
Update:
I was able to resolve this by removing the boundaries in the pattern
pattern = r'\b(%s)\b' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, s.index))
to
pattern = r'(%s)' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, s.index))

Had to remove duplicated indexes in the 's' series first, s = s[~s.index.duplicated(keep='first')] but your code replaced all macro_ids in a Sheet with over 10000 rows (repeated 4 sample lines provided) for me.

Thanks for checking it out. I'm  wondering if it could just be a bug with visual studio.

I use pycharm, but obviously you can try your code from the command line.

Update:
I was able to resolve this by removing the boundaries in the pattern
pattern = r'\b(%s)\b' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, s.index))
to
pattern = r'(%s)' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, s.index))
